# How to use different .ebextensions config files for different environments in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I successfully deployed my first application to Elastic Beanstalk with CodePipeline and CodeBuild. For setting up the **environment variables** I used a `.config` file inside the `.ebextensions` directory and everything worked fine. But I need to maintain two sets of the same environment variables for two different environments. I can't figure out that part.

**Below are what I've done so far and what I'm trying to do.**

In my `.ebextensions` directory I have two config files where I'm planning to set environment variables according to **development** and **production** environments. The problem is I can't figure out how to do this.

```
.ebextensions/
   - env_dev.config
   - env_prod.config
```

I'm using two CodePipeLines for deployments.

- Main branch -> production (need to use `env_prod.config`)
- Dev branch -> development (need to use `env_dev.config`)

**env_dev.config:**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    var1: val1
    var2: val2
```

**env_prod.config:**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    var1: val3
    var2: val4
```

Is this possible with this approach? If it is, how can I proceed from here? Any other solutions or suggestions for doing this are also welcome. Thank you.

---

**Update:**

Below is my `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - npm install -g typescript
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies and H5P core...
      - npm install
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - build/**/*
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - node_modules/**/*
    - .ebextensions/**/*
```

Comment: Are you working with a single instance which you would sometimes like to behave as development (and use the dev vars) and at other times behave as production (and use the prod vars)?

Comment: @dusthaines yes..

Comment: Ok, very helpful. We will still need some additional details to understand your deployment process - this will inform the best way to accomplish your goal. Can you share more details about how you deploy? Are you using the `eb cli` and `eb deploy` command, or some other process? Most important: each time you deploy to your single instance, how does it know whether you would like it to behave as `development` or `production`? Be aware what you are trying to do may expose security risks! If your `.config` files contain passwords, tokens, or keys, this is not the best way to manage them.